# Regular Expression not start with two 'WW' or 'MM'

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, angularjs, regex

1). modification require below  expression

`^.{0,100}$` this expression not begin with 'WW' or'MM' and not add spacial characters

other condition is

2). how can i add `^.{0,100}$` this condition in below expression

```
(?:WW[A-Za-z0-9]{10}|MM\d{8})$
```

Comment: It's unclear, but I'm guessing `^(?:WW[^\W_]{10}|MM\d{8}|.{100})$`

Answer (score 1):

For the first pattern, use a negative lookahead

```
^(?!WW|MM)[A-Za-z0-9]{0,100}$
```

For the second pattern, fill the rest for either part with any char until 100

```
^(?:WW[A-Za-z0-9]{10}.{88}|MM\d{8}.{90})$
```